# Python counting multiple modes in a list

Tags: python, list

This is a simple function but it is giving me a hard time. I'm trying to calculate the mode in a list, and if there are > 1 modes (with the same frequency), then they need to be displayed.

```
def compute_mode(numbers):
mode = 0
count = 0
maxcount = 0
for number in numbers:
    count = numbers.count(number)
    if count >= maxcount:
        maxcount = count
        mode = number
        print("Mode: ", mode, "Count: ", maxcount)
```

Function call:

```
print(compute_mode([0,1,3,5,7,3,0]))
```

Output:

```
Mode:  0 Count:  2
Mode:  3 Count:  2
Mode:  3 Count:  2
Mode:  0 Count:  2
```

I can't seem to make the function not repeat the last two lines. I'm not sure why it is repeating again for 0 and 3.

Any ideas?

Comment: As it stands the `for` loop may cause numbers to be cited as modes even if they are not modes.  Your code will claim a number is a mode if its count equals or exceeds the maximum count ***so far***, not the maximum count overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get the modes twice is that your for-loop loops over every element in the list. Therefore, when it encounters the second instance of a previously seen element, it prints it out again.

In other news, your function will fail for a different reason - try removing the first `0` and see what happens.

This is how I would fix it:

```
from collections import Counter

def compute_mode(numbers):
    counts = Counter(numbers)
    maxcount = max(counts.values())
    for num,count in counts:
        if count == maxcount:
            print(num, count)
```

If you want to do all the heavy lifting yourself:

```
def compute_mode(numbers):
    counts = {}
    maxcount = 0
    for number in numbers:
        if number not in counts:
            counts[number] = 0
        counts[number] += 1
        if counts[number] > maxcount:
            maxcount = counts[number]

    for number, count in counts.items():
        if count == maxcount:
            print(number, count)
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now. Any reason why "None" is printed after the result?

Comment: @Pythonguy: that's not a print. When you call the function from the python shell, the return value of the function is `None`, because it doesn't return anything. Since you call the function from the shell, its return value will also be displayed on screen, which is why you see `None`

Comment: Ah, thank you. I removed the print() from the function call and all is well now.

Answer (score 3):

Its repeating those lines, simply because you have 2 of those numbers in your list.

Your function doesn't track if its already seen a number, in order to update a counter for it.

To count things, use the appropriately named `Counter` from the `collections` module:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([0,1,3,5,7,3,0]).most_common()
[(0, 2), (3, 2), (1, 1), (5, 1), (7, 1)]
```

Or, the other way to do this is to keep track of a number you have already seen, and just update its counter in a dictionary (which is similar to how `Counter` works), using a `defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for i in [0,1,3,5,7,3,0]:
...   d[i] += 1
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {0: 2, 1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 1, 7: 1})
>>> for item, count in d.items():
...    print('Mode: {} Count: {}'.format(item, count))
...
Mode: 0 Count: 2
Mode: 1 Count: 1
Mode: 3 Count: 2
Mode: 5 Count: 1
Mode: 7 Count: 1
```

Comment: Good simple usage of Counter().most_common(). That's a great built in solution.